# React Table not displaying data properly

Tags: reactjs, react-table-v6

I am using React-Table-V6 and have trouble understanding why my data is not being rendered:

```
const sanArrayCols = [
  {Header: 'Serial No.', accessor: 'serialNumber'}
];

let temp = [{
  serialNumber: '1'
}];

<ReactTable 
  data={temp}
  columns={sanArrayCols}
  defaultPageSize={10}
  pageSize={[10, 20, 30]}/>
```

Yet, my table is not showing me anything. I am not sure what is wrong at this moment

Answer (score 0):

You need to install react-table-6 with npm as:
`npm i react-table-6`

then you need to import:
`import ReactTable from 'react-table-6';`
`import 'react-table-6/react-table.css';`

Your code does not contain errors and will word. I made a React functional component to test it.

`import React from "react";`
`import ReactTable from 'react-table-6';`
`import 'react-table-6/react-table.css';`

`export default function Rtable() {`
`const sanArrayCols = [`
  `{Header: 'Serial No.', accessor: 'serialNumber'}`
`];`

`let temp = [{`
  `serialNumber: '1'`
`}];`

`return (`
    `<div>`
      `<ReactTable columns={sanArrayCols} data={temp} ></ReactTable>`
    `</div>`
  `);`
`}`